# How do I simply print a raw json string?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to get at the underlying data for this mess.  It's a GKE-specific PubSub message and I don't know what the underlying JSON looks like.  There's also an attributes key in the json and that's what I'm most interested in.  Is there a way I can just dump the incoming json so I can see what it looks like?

```
// Package p contains a Pub/Sub Cloud Function.
package p

import (
    "context"
    "log"
)

// PubSubMessage is the payload of a Pub/Sub event. Please refer to the docs for
// additional information regarding Pub/Sub events.
type PubSubMessage struct {
    Data []byte `json:"data"`
}

// HelloPubSub consumes a Pub/Sub message.
func HelloPubSub(ctx context.Context, m PubSubMessage) error {
    log.Println(string(m.Data))
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(&m)
```

should encode as json and write to stdout